# Inserting picture from userform to xlApp instance fails

Tags: excel, vba, image, object, userform

I'm writing code inside MS Project and building a report for Excel.

**Goal:** Insert a picture from a userform located in MS Project into the xlApp instance of Excel created by my Sub

**Problem:** Setting the userform image fails, I think it's because of working with "2 environments"

I got this sub placed inside a userform in MS Project:

```
Sub printToExcel()
Dim xlApp, xlBook, xlSheet  As Object
Dim img As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

With xlSheet
    Set img = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.image.1", _
        Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
        Left:=.Range("D1").Left, _
        Top:=.Range("D1").Top, _
        Width:=Me.Image1.Width, _
        Height:=Me.Image1.Height)
End With

With img
      .Object.PictureSizeMode = 0
      .Object.Picture = Me.Image1.Picture
End With
End Sub
```

The code fails on the line where it's trying to set the picture: `.Object.Picture = Me.Image1.Picture`

The excact same code fails in Excel if I create a userform in Excel with an image, then try to create a new Excel instance and insert it there. But works if I leave out the new Excel instance and just insert it in the same document. So I guess I have to be more specific on what userform holds the original picture? Do I have to somehow specify what VBCompontent that holds the picture? Any ideas?

I was hoping I didn't have to temporary save the file on disk before inserting, but I know that's a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up. Seems to be a different task when working with an Excel instance rather that coding it inside the actual Excel workbook. I ended up saving to disk...